# Ubuntu 21.10 on GPD Win Max 2021: touchpad click/hold/drag with second finger

Tags: drivers, gnome, usb, touchpad

I have a new Win Max 2021 (Intel edition) from GPD. In Windows, as shipped, the touchpad lets you point at something, hold down to click and drag, and then with a second finger drag to whatever you want the new location to be. In Ubuntu I can't figure out how to enable this behavior. ETA: according to the Windows driver, this is a device from "Goodix," if that helps.

This is what I get from `lsusb`:

```
jtd@Volantis:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0764 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB Storage
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2f24:0118   Mouse for Windows
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Ah, yes, well-known device manufacturer "space space Mouse for Windows."

Not sure the `lsmod` output is all that useful, but:

```
jtd@Volantis:~$ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  4
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 28672  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    98304  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_cadence      32768  1 soundwire_intel
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               135168  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    49152  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_bus          81920  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof
snd_soc_core          290816  4 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
intel_tcc_cooling      16384  0
snd_hda_codec         147456  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_hda_core           94208  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
coretemp               20480  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
joydev                 28672  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
snd_pcm               118784  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
kvm_intel             290816  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
i915                 2428928  15
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlmvm                425984  0
kvm                   872448  1 kvm_intel
mac80211             1024000  1 iwlmvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
aesni_intel           376832  8
drm_kms_helper        262144  1 i915
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
btusb                  61440  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
rc_core                57344  1 cec
btintel                32768  1 btusb
intel_cstate           20480  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
bluetooth             663552  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
iwlwifi               376832  1 iwlmvm
snd                    94208  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
processor_thermal_device    20480  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
processor_thermal_rfim    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
input_leds             16384  0
hid_multitouch         28672  0
processor_thermal_mbox    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
serio_raw              20480  0
processor_thermal_rapl    20480  1 processor_thermal_device
mei_me                 40960  1
wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_rapl
cfg80211              892928  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
efi_pstore             16384  0
intel_pmt_telemetry    16384  0
mei                   131072  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
intel_pmt_class        16384  1 intel_pmt_telemetry
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
goodix                 28672  0
intel_hid              24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 intel_hid
int3403_thermal        20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    20480  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
mac_hid                16384  0
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_tad               20480  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             45056  0
drm                   561152  8 drm_kms_helper,i915
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
usbhid                 61440  0
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
hid_generic            16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
r8169                  94208  0
i2c_i801               36864  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
realtek                32768  1
intel_pmt              16384  0
thunderbolt           266240  0
nvme                   45056  2
intel_lpss_pci         24576  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
nvme_core             126976  3 nvme
xhci_pci               20480  0
idma64                 20480  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof
i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
i2c_hid                28672  1 i2c_hid_acpi
hid                   135168  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
video                  53248  1 i915
pinctrl_tigerlake      32768  3
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work? I tried the regular Settings panel, gnome-tweaks and touche, and none of them seem to have anything to do with this feature.

Thanks!